# C SDL2 write text to canvas segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, sdl-2, webassembly

I'm trying to use C to create a webassembly program to write text to an HTML5 canvas. I'm getting a segfault.
I've been looking at this tutorial: https://lyceum-allotments.github.io/2016/06/emscripten-and-sdl2-tutorial-part-6-write-owl/

This is my main.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>


/**
 * A Context structure that can be used to pass variables into the loop
 */ 
// 
struct Context {
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    int iteration;

    // Rectangle that texture will be rendered into
    TTF_Font *font;
    SDL_Texture *text_texture;
} Context;



/** 
 * size of the canvas in pixels 
 */
const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1600;
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 420;

void set_font_text(struct Context *ctx, const char *text) {
    SDL_Color fg = {0,0,0,255};
    SDL_Surface *text_surface = TTF_RenderText_Blended(ctx->font, text, fg);
    ctx->text_texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ctx->renderer, text_surface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(text_surface);

    SDL_DestroyTexture(ctx->text_texture);
}

int get_font_texture(struct Context *ctx) {
    ctx->font = TTF_OpenFont("assets/fonts/Alef-Regular.ttf", 30);
    set_font_text(ctx, "NEIL DU TOIT");
    TTF_CloseFont(ctx->font);
    TTF_Quit();
    return 1;
}


/**
 * The loop handler, will be called repeatedly
 */ 
void mainLoop(void *arg) {
    struct Context *ctx = arg;

    // Set background color and clear canvas
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ctx->renderer, 100, 143, 154, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(ctx->renderer);

    SDL_Rect text_dest = {.x = 50, .y = 175, .w = 0, .h = 0};
    SDL_QueryTexture(ctx->text_texture, NULL, NULL, &text_dest.w, &text_dest.h);
    SDL_RenderCopy(ctx->renderer, ctx->text_texture, NULL, &text_dest);
    SDL_RenderPresent(ctx->renderer);
}


int main() {
    SDL_Window *window;
    struct Context ctx;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    TTF_Init();

    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0, &window, &ctx.renderer);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ctx.renderer, 255, 143, 154, 255);

    get_font_texture(&ctx);

    ctx.iteration = 0;

    int infinite_loop = 1;
    int fps = -1;
    emscripten_set_main_loop_arg(mainLoop, &ctx, fps, infinite_loop);

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ctx.renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comiled using:

```
emcc main.c -s USE_SDL=2 -s WASM=1 -s USE_SDL_TTF=2 -O3 -o main.js
```

and served with:

```
python3 -m http.server 8000
```

When opened I immediately see:
[image]

If I remove the call to set_font_text the error goes away (but I don't see any text of course)

What's going wrong?

Comment: The first step in debugging should be to check the return values of the functions that you are calling, to see if they are indicating an error.

Comment: Also make sure that all pointers you have are initialized, and not null.